# Output a mySQL query to CSV with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv

So I have a decent size database (roughly 8 million rows) that I need to pull data from. It needs to be output into a CSV that can be opened by Excel. I've tried virtually every solution I found, to no avail.

\copy - Puts all values in a single column, separated by ','.

copy...to...with csv header - same result as above.

copy...into outfile - refuses to work. Claims there's something wrong with my path, when I used the same path as before

I'm not the most experienced with my SQL to say the least, but I'll try my best to provide any information necessary.

Comment: Why is this tagged as both mysql and postgresql?  Which database are you using?

I've never had problems with postgres using psql with
`\copy (SELECT * FROM table) TO ~/my/file/path.csv CSV HEADER`

Comment: Do you mean "output an SQL query to CSV"? Outputting a MySQL query with Postgres makes no sense. As for "a single column, separated by ,", isn't that exactly what a CSV file is? What does the actual text of the CSV file look like, if you open it in something other than Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try mysql DUMP?

I have experience like you, to backup or upload 11 million data.

And success with mysqlDUMP, maybe you can seach like mysqldump for PostGresql